# Is it possible to decrypt remote files with key stored in pageant(local)

Tags: linux, ssh, encryption, putty, private-key

I connect from my windows desktop to linux(centos) vps using pytty, authenticating with key stored in pageant. Now I would like to store passwords in encrypted file and use them in scripts, but without server side keyring. Is it possible to use key stored in my local pageant to decrypt remote file? If yes, how to set it up?

EDIT: If no, is there a pageant alternative that can do both: authentication and remote file decryption (or passing key to remote keyring)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with an SSH agent because it's only intended for handling SSH authentication challenges. It is possible with a GPG key and [gpg-agent](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html)[0], but requires some manual work to get it forwarded over the SSH connection.

[0] I don't know if this is available for Windows.

Comment: I figured out the solution with gpg(server side) but that woud ask me for passphrase once per session, which I would like to avoid (that's why I use pageant in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Pageant is specifically designed for SSH authentication. Using it to store passwords or decrypt files might be possible but it would be a hack; it isn't the right tool for the job.

If you want something to store your passwords in an encrypted form, maybe [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) or one of the many similar products would work better for you.